# Why is this button still displaying upon loading a new component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load items from an RSS feed once the view more button is clicked. I successfully load the items however, the button still appears. What am I doing wrong/how do I fix this?

Here is what is displayed before clicking the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaMSe.png

Here is what is displayed after clicking the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56mmJ.png

### Home.js

```
function Home() {

  
  
  return(
  

    
      <Router><Link to="/marinersfeed">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2"> <Button size='lg' id='billsViewMoreButton'> View More</Button> </div>
      </Link><Route path="/marinersfeed" component={MarinersFeed} /></Router>

    
    
  )
}

export default Home;
```

MarinersFeed.js

```
function MarinersFeed() {

      


      const [completeFeed, setCompletedFeed] = React.useState([]);
      const [feedTitle, setFeedTitle] = React.useState([]);
      const [feedLink, setFeedLink] = React.useState([]);

      

      React.useEffect(async () => {
            
            let Parser = require('rss-parser');
            let parser = new Parser();

            const tFeed = [];
            const tFeedTitle = [];
            const tFeedLink = []
            
         
            let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://*******.herokuapp.com/https://www.mlb.com/mariners/feeds/news/rss.xml');
            feed.items.forEach(item => {

                  tFeed.push(item.title + ':' + item.link);
                  tFeedTitle.push(item.title);
                  tFeedLink.push(item.link);
                  

            });

            setCompletedFeed(tFeed);
            setFeedTitle(tFeedTitle);
            setFeedLink(tFeedLink);


      }, []);

           
      const renderData = () => {
            return completeFeed.map((f, index) => {

                  const title = feedTitle[index];
                  const link = feedLink[index];

                  return <div key={index} >

                        
                        <h3>{title}</h3>

                        <h3>{link}</h3>

                  </div>
            })
      }




          
            
            return(
                  <>
                        
                        {renderData()}
                  </>
            )
            
      }

export default MarinersFeed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place Link as  separate route.

Even though route is changed on button click and RSS Feed is displayed.The Link is displayed as it is not part of any separate Route but just placed in Router .

```html
 <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/marinerFeed">
          <MarinersFeed />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Link to="/marinerFeed">Button</Link>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to where to put this within my code.

Comment: Can you show me what the whole implementation would look like. I am lost.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-hill-836nw 
Here is an example using with Switch

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now. You have no idea how helpful this is. Godspeed!